# Artifactory 5.2.0: managing non-incremental backups

Tags: backup, artifactory

We have set up a test artifactory server.

We tried to edit the pre-defined `backup-daily` plan by **unchecking** the `Incremental` checkbox and clicking `Save`.

However, when going back to the edit screen, the check box remains **checked**.

Is there a reason for that?

This also happens when defining a new (custom) back up plan.

The `Incremental` check box seems to always remain checked.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/600869f83b08cfd5d50fb7593a856778) is the system info.

Here are the logs when going through the process of unchecking `Incremental` checkbox and clicking `Save`.

```
2017-04-07 09:50:35,126 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:394) - Reloading configuration...
2017-04-07 09:50:35,127 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:250) - Saving new configuration in storage...
2017-04-07 09:50:35,154 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:254) - New configuration saved.
2017-04-07 09:50:35,156 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:433) - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by reload
2017-04-07 09:50:36,561 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.s.BaseTaskServiceDescriptorHandler:51) - No Replication configured. Replication is disabled.
2017-04-07 09:50:36,584 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:433) - Artifactory application context set to READY by reload
2017-04-07 09:50:36,586 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:406) - Configuration reloaded.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you entered a retention period?

When not using the incremental backup you have to specify the retention period in order for it to "stick".
Just to be on the safe side, you can't use "0" as this is reserved to incremental.

Comment: Thank you! That was what was missing.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)